# Not getting expected output in my terminal

Tags: terminal, output, quest, sui

i was solving a quest in stackup. The quest is on SUI move. its quest 3. I've almost done it but the last step is not as expected. i had to get the unit test in terminal and the result was unexpected. The result should be test 1,passed 1,failed 0. But i've got 0 for every attribute. I tried every possibility but didn't work.

I did everything as directed i completed my module perfectly. but the unit test i had test0 passed 0 and failed 0. As the expected output was test1 , passed 1, failed0 in the terminal.

Comment: And now?  How would anyone be able to help your without knowing the contents of that quest?  Please use [edit] to add that to your question (because it should be in your question, and not on an external website), and share the solution you made.